# Were any of the The Matrix movies released with extended editions?

Tags: alternate-version, the-matrix, the-matrix-reloaded, the-matrix-revolutions, the-animatrix

So far I've looked at the [Ultimate Matrix Collection on Blu-Ray](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OPPBEQ), which to me seems like the most complete and recent version out there, but the product description makes no mention of extra scenes.

IMDB's [Alternative Versions](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133093/alternateversions) entry doesn't mention anything significant, although  I've noticed that it doesn't always seem to be complete, and I've heard it [mentioned](https://www.matrixfans.net/tag/the-matrix-reloaded-extended-edition/) in several places that at least The Matrix Reloaded had an additional hour of footage.

I've also noticed that on certain [special features](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0439486/), some cast are credited as being only in the extended version, although it only mentions that it has a total running time of [176 minutes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0439486/alternateversions?ref_=tt_ql_trv_5).

Comment: I don't know how you could "prove" that an extended version does not exist, short of exhaustively checking every worldwide release of the film from the last 20+ years…but having followed the various re-releases of the Matrix films reasonably closely in that time, I have never heard of any extended edition of any of them.

Comment: The comments under the accepted answer seem to address this, but those references to the "extended version" on IMDB appear to be in reference to the behind-the-scenes documentary "The Burly Man Chronicles," and not to the movies themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the Ultimate Matrix Collection, and I can confirm that extended versions don't exist for any of The Matrix movies.

The collection comes with several DVDs, one of which in The Burly Man Chronicles, which contains many extras and interviews with people who aren't in the movie (such as critics, scholars, etc).

The link you provided is simply a forum and fan speculation about the Ultimate Matrix Collection.

Comment: It sounds like you can confirm whether the Ultimate Matrix Collection doesn't have extended versions, but not for any other releases. I know for a fact that early DVD boxsets have different content to the Blu-Ray so I don't think those can be ruled out, although the fan speculation theory is what I initially suspected and would make sense. The extra features and footage in that version are for the Enter the Matrix videogame fyi not for Path of Neo. With regards to The Burly Man Chronicles, is it the extended version on the UMC or the standard version?

Comment: The extended version is in the UMC. When this collection first came out, I went though in detail to find out what features were available, it seems the studio packed everything. You get the 3 movies and all the extra content that came with those movies, plus a lot more.

Comment: What makes me know there is some content not included on the UMC that was included on earlier DVD boxsets is the final paragraph of this article: https://www.matrixfans.net/the-last-word-on-the-matrix-collection-set-2/. The chances of that different content being actual extended scenes are probably pretty slim, but perhaps still possible. Just need someone with those DVD versions to rule it out.

Comment: @Hashim - The problem is all of this is speculation. Being a die-hard Matrix fan, I've never heard the brothers gave any statement on DVD extras. I think the site was made and published before the collection was released and is running wild with *industry insiders* claiming to know what's official.

Comment: Another thing, if extended editions exist, they would have been released as a standalone DVD first before being part of a collection. Studios want to make money and this is just one of the ways do that. BattleStar Galactica did this, they released the first half of the season on DVD followed by the second half on another DVD, only to provide the full season DVD at the end.

Answer (score 1):

There definitely are alternate versions. Right now, I'm watching Australian YouTubers 'Nics&Nacs' react to The Matrix and I'm watching a bathroom fight scene where Morpheus knocks Smith's sunglasses off with a headbutt, provoking Smith to return several hard headbutts. This is an extended scene. I've watched the theatrical version in Europe on VHS and on the Ultimate Collection DVD multiple times. This scene was not in them. In the original European theatrical version, it just cuts from Smith on the ground wearing his sunglasses, to him rising upright with his glasses magically vanished. I always thought it was a continuation error. I had no idea until now that a scene existed that show Morpheus knocking his glasses off.

Comment: Maybe post a comment or send an email asking what version they were watching?

Comment: That scene was in the US theatrical release and on all the formats I've seen. Maybe there are UNextended (edited) releases, but that doesn't make the original "extended."

Comment: Headbutts are a common target of censorship. Here's an example of a UK release of The Matrix missing the headbutt scene: https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=4004